# Can downtime be solved with multiple servers?

Tags: asp.net, dns, web-hosting, downtime

I have tried many hosting services and they all have the downtime problem. Now, i am well aware that downtime  is inevitable and will happend eventually, but i have been wandering if a website can be hosted in multiple hostings to solve this problem. For example, i have my website in one hosting company and if for any reason  my site goes down in that site, my domain name can redirect to the alternative hosting company.

Is that posible? and if so, how can it be done?

I will greatly apreciate any help.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about servers. This would probably be a better fit for http://serverfault.com/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to have 100% uptime guaranteed, but having multiple servers spread across multiple providers can get you close.

The trick is letting your DNS know which IP to serve your site from. My DNS provider has a failover system that monitors my sites; if it detects any downtime, it automatically serves up a secondary IP address for requests to my domain.

Of course, this requires having an infrastructure in place to ensure the content is synced across multiple servers but if you're in the game for a failover system like this I'm guessing you've already got something like that in place.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Your answer pointed me in the right direction and now i am good to go.